# Which gfortran compiler support "real*16 or real(kind=16)" under scientific linux 6?

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran

I am currently using gfortran 4.4.7 compiler under scientific linux 6.
I need to declare variables with 128-bit.
I cannot change the O.S.
I hope there is something that I can do under scientific linux 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install gfortran 4.6 or newer; support for REAL(KIND=16) has been added there with libquadmath. Preferably, you should install latest 4.9 version; IIRC some libquadmath-related bugs have been fixed in the meantime.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#gfortran_4.6 .

Comment: I am not sure but I was told that I cannot install any newer compiler version than 4.4.7 on my current OS (scientific linux 6).

Comment: "cannot" or "are not allowed to"?  Installing gfortran from source on Linux is rather straightforward.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#FromSource

Comment: I am in a beginner level and believe everyone who seems to be pro in linux :) Thank you for your time and efforts.